# Calling collection from firebase comes up empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get some information from a firebase collection called "notifications" in order to notify users when their questions have been answered. The problem is when I call the collection it comes back as an empty array.

Here is the code where I am calling information from firebase. I use a console log to call the database on line 34:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import NotificationsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";
import "../Style/Header.css";
import db from "../firebase";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        border: "1px solid",
        padding: theme.spacing(1),
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
        zIndex: "10",
    },
}));

export default function SimplePopper() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
    };

    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const id = open ? "simple-popper" : undefined;

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("notifications")
            // .where("user.askerUserId", "==", auth.currentUser.uid)
            .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                console.log(snapshot.docs);
                setNotifications(
                    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                        id: doc.id,
                        content: doc.data().content,
                    }))
                );
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="header__icon">
            <NotificationsIcon
                aria-describedby={id}
                type="button"
                onClick={handleClick}
            />
            <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} style={{ zIndex: 100 }}>
                <div className={classes.paper}>
                    <ul className="notifications">
                        {notifications.map((notification) => (
                            <li key={notification.id}>{notification.content}</li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Popper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you *know* the documents have a "timestamp" field?  Firestore does *not* add them automatically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LeadDreamer pointed this out. The issue was that I didn't correctly label the "timestamp" field when I posted the document to firestore, which I assumed firebase added them automatically. Instead I had it listed as "time".

Here is the code that was in the firebase functions index.js file that I changed that made it work:

```
exports.answerCreated = functions.firestore
  .document("questions/{questionsId}/answer/{answerId}")
  .onCreate(async (doc) => {
    const project = doc.data();
    const { displayName, uid } = project.user;
    const questionSnapshot = await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("questions")
      .doc(project.questionId)
      .get();
    const question = questionSnapshot.data();
    if (question) {
      const { user } = question;
      const notification = {
        content: "Added an answer",
        user: {
          askerUserId: user.uid,
          displayName,
          uid,
        },
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      };

      return createNotification(notification);
    }
  });
```